# Error creating multiple tables sqlite android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm tired of trying all the methods to solve what the title says, this is my code:

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String nombre, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table usuarios(placaVehiculo text primary key, tipoVehiculo text )");
        db.execSQL("create table configuraciones(indicador text primary key, descripcion text )");

   }

}
```

the table called "usuarios" is created, but the table called "configuraciones" is not created, i do not know what else, what i can do to create more than two tables??, pls help me.

This is the parametres when i called the database:

```
 AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
 SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: What does LogCat say?

Comment: say nothing, i just cant acces to the second table, is not created

Comment: some like, no such table: "configuraciones"

Comment: Just to confirm, are you deleting the database file between runs? If you didn't have the second create table command the first time the DB was created, it's won't run onCreate again while that DB is still present...